# How can i get the stripe error in a json laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an ionic app that makes a request to my laravel server to make the payment on the stripe platform.
but causing the error returns the Handler.php error and I cannot access the object.

How do I get the **"Your card has insufficient funds."** in a **json**?
to later show it in my app.

I already tried the try and catch and keep sending the error in handle

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Azx.png)

My controller:

```
 try {
                //Charge the Card
            $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
                'source' => $request->token,
                'currency' => $reservation->divisa_code,
                'amount'   => $reservation->total_price_divisa,
                'description' => "App Payment Booking Seadust Cancun",
                'receipt_email' => $guest->email                
            ]);
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
            //Send User to Error Page
            return $e;
        } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            return $body;
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            //Send User to Error Page
            return $e;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        };
```

Comment: can you please show the controller code?

Comment: edit the post, thanks

Comment: are you using cartalyst/stripe?

Comment: Yes,  Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe;

Comment: The strange thing is that when it is a successful payment if you return a json

Answer (score 0):

I think you are catching the wrong exception (check [here](https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#exceptions)), you probably should have something like this:

```
try {
    //Charge the Card
    $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
        'source' => $request->token,
        'currency' => $reservation->divisa_code,
        'amount'   => $reservation->total_price_divisa,
        'description' => "App Payment Booking Seadust Cancun",
        'receipt_email' => $guest->email                
    ]);
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    //Send User to Error Page
    return $e;
} catch (Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\CardErrorException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
    // or if you want a "bad response" in case of exception
    // abort(404, $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e;
};
```

Comment: try with your code and it does not enter the catch it automatically goes to handle.php and shows me the error from the template and not in json :(

Comment: @DannuuGomez well are you sure that this is the code that is been executed?...